# Generate python code of a class from an python instance of this class

Tags: python, code-generation, metaprogramming

In my code, I generate new python classes at runtime. For some of them, I want to generate the python code, just as if I wrote these classes in a .py file.

Let's say that I created dynamically a class A:
`type('A', (), {'bar':True}` which is equivalent to the code:

```
class A(object): 
    bar=True
```

What I want is to generate this equivalent code from my dynamic class.
I'm trying to implement a function "generate_A_code"

```
kls_A = type('A', (), {'bar':True}
kls_A.generate_A_code()
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give a simple example, with some code and an explanation of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Now, what *exactly* do you mean by "I created dynamically a class A"? It sounds like it's not part of your `.py` file, nor do you generate the code as a string and `eval` it... so what it is that you do exactly?

Comment: Here is an example of what I wrote to create dynamically a class: Foo = type('Foo', (), {'bar':True})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating the Python code from the class object itself is practically impossible. You need to save the instructions for generating the class in another way.

---

The best way may be having a function to make the class, and importing & calling it in the generated code. So the generated code would look like this:

```
kwargs = {answer=42, name='foo'}

import class_maker
SomeClass1 = class_maker.make_class(**kwargs)
```

---

The other option is generate the Python code you want directly, `exec` it to make the class, and then save it with the class.

```
code = '''class MyClass:
    pass
'''

the_locals = {}
exec(code, globals(), the_locals)
MyClass = the_locals['MyClass']
MyClass._code = code
```

As always with `exec`, be very careful using it. It can run any Python code. Think hard if there's any way to do whatever you need to do in a different way. People will shout at you for using `exec`. (But even the  Python standard library uses it for dynamic classes [sometimes](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l293).)

Comment: Yes it seems really hard. I will try to generate it by another way. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`compile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile), [`exec()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) or [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) depending on your exact needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I was not clear in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [inspect.getsource](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource):

```
import inspect

def generate_kls_A(num):
    class A(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.init = num
    return A
kls_A=generate_kls_A(1)
print(inspect.getsource(kls_A))
```

yields:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init = num
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately, inspect.getsource does not work if you generate your class with type('A', () {'bar':True})